# Display text when hover only using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hover, display

#### Nothing

[image]

#### When Hovered

[image]

How do I display a text in the middle of the image only using css.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please show us your HTML and CSS! (maybe read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) )

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you if you don't post your code!

Comment: Ok.  That's not entirely true because I have an idea of how to help you, but just so you know, you will lose reputation incredibly quickly in the future if you do not post code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="hover" />
    <p class="text">text</p>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
    #wrapper .text {
    position:relative;
    bottom:30px;
    left:0px;
    visibility:hidden;
    }

    #wrapper:hover .text {
    visibility:visible;
    }
```

```
[Demo][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
a.transparent {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: url("whatever.jpg");
display: block;
text-decoration: none; 
}

a.transparent span span{
color:transparent;
}
a:hover.transparent span{
display:block;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
a:hover.transparent span span{
display:block;
padding-top: 33%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.5em;
line-height: 1em;
background:transparent;
color: #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="transparent"><span><span>Rocket<br />League</span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It is fully tested and hope it will helpful for you.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ybfu.png" class="hover" />
    <p class="title">Rocket<br> League</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width:300px;
}
.title {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  right:0;
  top:50%;
  bottom:0;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: red;
  display:none;
}
#container:hover .title {
  display:block;
}
```